# JSONP , Portholes, and other CrossDomain strategies

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm currently working on a SaaS platform that will use at least two domains:

- (a) http://example.com
- (b) https://example.com

and will likely use additional custom domains...

- (c) http://example.net
- (d) http://example.org
- (e) https://example.net
- (f) https://example.org

I'm trying to devise a strategy to enable a fair amount of security when using all of the domains, while at the same time consolidating all of the remote calls and "widget" interaction to *Domain(b)* [ https://example.com ].

( quick note - i'm using "widget" as a general term.  these are on the source HTML page , not iframe drop-ins or javascript document-writes. )

After going through piles of documentation on Portholes, JSONP, Cross Domain Scripting , Browser Security Models, and the like... I've come up with this general idea.  I'm hoping for some feedback...

1. A login onto the 'network' creates an auxiliary cookie for *Domain(b)* -- *WidgetSession*
2. Visits to all the domains fetch Domain(b)/javascript/utils.js
3. Visits to domains other than Domain(b) fetch Domain(b)/api/widget-session.js , which has a callback to register the active *WidgetSession* into the utils.js javascript package.
4. All API interactions occur via the *WidgetSession* cookie, which is only valid for a set number of activities.

With this strategy, I seem to be able to get around all of the browser security lockdowns , there's not much work involved , and there is minimized + little risk/exposure to the consumer.

Can anyone point out any pitfalls or offer better suggestions ?

I tried to take an iframe approach (using the porthole.js library), and that worked across domains, but I kept getting blocked in the browser when it came to protocols.  this sounds simpler and safer, though it wouldn't benefit from caching as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that cookies from 3rd party domains are already rejected by safari, and also will in the future for firefox.

Furthermore, using JSONP in combination with cookies is (always?) vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

**Edit** commenting is broken for me on stackoverflow, so responding here. The Firefox/Safari issue was a guess, so I'm not a 100% sure. I actually think the best way to go about it, is the iframe approach.. I guess 'porthole' does this. If you're having issues crossing over http / https, make sure you support both.. If the 'client' runs on a https url, your iframe should also be served from https.

Comment: I came to the above idea after a lot of reading and then testing on Safari and Firefox.

Comment: The workaround this seems to offer, is that the cookie is only used on the script tag embed. ( On domainC we link to an jsonp embed on domainB ).  That effectively just echoes back the cookie values of data for domainB in jsonp , so domainC can access them.  None of the rest of this workaround requires cookie interaction.  This currently works in safari and Firefox -- is it your understanding that the scheduled deprecation will cover this?  I should see if my ex-Mozilla friends still have contacts there.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking through your previous activity, I'm going to take your recommendation/preference.  `Porthole` is a lightweight iframe tool ( https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole ).  After doing a lot of investigating, it seems that the security lockdowns I thought I was dealing with , were non-existant.  I had some test code that was checking the window.location vs window.parent.location , and that was throwing errors.